# AngularJS gives 'Cannot get /page' when routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use angular-route to perform routing on my angularJS app. However, when I try to load /sales in the browser nothing appears (I tried with '#' and I get the same result). Here's my **main.js** file:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @name Main module
 * @description
 */
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/sales', {
    controller  : 'SalesCtrl',
    templateUrl : '/views/sales.html'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Here's my **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>webapp</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
      (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
      function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
      e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
      ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/sales.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/appconfig.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/sales.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <div ng-app="app">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using angular 1.6.1.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: any console errors? please provide the logs if any

Comment: Use $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); if you set true it will remove # from Url and angular routing will not work without # prefix.

Comment: @Anirudha there's any error in the console.

Comment: @shiva same result when I set $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

Comment: I was facing same issue with : 1.6.1 ---- >

    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

these changes worked for me.

Comment: Hi @shiva, I just added $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); and everything worked (but works only when I turn off html5mode). Thank you very much!

Comment: I will add it in ans section, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 1.6.1 default hashPrefix is now ! as stated in the docs and the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-1)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

This should work.

Comment: Awesome! I did not notice yet that they changed the default behaviour. You might to point out in your answer that the default `hashPrefix` is now `!` as stated in the docs and the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-1)

Comment: Sure i will do that, Thank you @TamasHegedus

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

And visit `http://yourapp.com/#/page` instead of `http://yourapp.com/page`

Comment: I get the same result when I set html5Mode to 'false' and change the url.